# how to activate debugInfoEnabled only for Unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

In my angularjs 1.3 app, i disabled debug info to increase performance :

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```

But when i launch my Jasmine tests with Karma, i got error with isolateScope :

```
var isoScope = element.isolateScope();
```

I know that it is completely normal,
but i'm looking for a way to reactivate the debug just for testing.
Can i do it programmatically ?
Can i define that in the karma-unit.conf.js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to this was to create a set of config files, the load specific files via grunt or gulp, depending on the task or environment variables.

example config:

```
// configFileLocal.js
angular.module('myapp.config')
.constant('apiUrl', 'https://myapi.com/api')
.constant('debugInfoState', true);
```

an excerpt from Gruntfile:

```
copy: {
  test: {
    src: (function () {
      var filename;
      if (process.env.REMOTE_TESTS) {
        filename = './config-files/configFileTestsRemote.js';
      } else {
        filename = './config-files/configFileTestsLocal.js';
      }
      return filename;
    })(),
    dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/root/config.js',
  },
  dev: {
    src: './config-files/configFileLocal.js',
    dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/root/config.js',
  },
  ...
```

then of course you need to load it in your app like this:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.config(function ($compileProvider, debugInfoState) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(debugInfoState);
});
```

so /app/scripts/root/config.js is overwritten every time.
in index.html, the only file that is loaded is /app/scripts/root/config.js
this task should be run before any concatenation tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from [wiherek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2445063/wiherek) is good but it isn't necessary to use your grun/gulp to manage this. Just transform snippet from [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) to something like this

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp', function (_$compileProvider_) {
        _$compileProvider_.debugInfoEnabled(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(!!window.__karma__);
```

Answer (score -2):

To debug an application after disabling debugInfo, you should open your console and run this code directly from your console:

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();
```

This will reload your page with all debugging info.

Comment: I cannot do this in the context of unit tests with Jasmine !

Comment: This does NOT work while testing, it's meant to enable the debug as per the docs.